# Spring can't make static reference to non-static method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, static

This is my PageController code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/show/category/{id}/products" })
public ModelAndView showCategoryProducts(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

    // Category DAO  //Getting Error Here
    Category category = null;//Please  Explain this line also.
    category = CategoryDAO.get(id);// Getting Error in this line

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
    mv.addObject("title", "All Products");
    // Passing list of categories
    mv.addObject("categories", categoryDAO.list());
    mv.addObject("userClickCategoryProducts", true);
    return mv;
}
```

Code in CategoreDAO Class

```
public interface CategoryDAO {
    List<Category> list();
    Category get(int id);
}
```

Another class Which Implements CategoryDAO class

```
Repository("CategoryDAO")
public class CategoryDAOImpl implements CategoryDAO {
    private static List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    static {@Override
    public Category get(int id) {

        for(Category category:categories) {
            if(category.getId()==id)
                return category;
        }

    return null;
}
```

I am getting an error that static reference can't make non-static method.

Please take a look in the first code snippet. You'll understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Absolutely.

Static and non static object work differently.
With non static method, you must instantiate before using.
So that's why it's not valid to use non static method in static method.

One more thing, the static block will be invoked before constructor. So please double check your business logic. I don't understand so much why to override other function in static block.